# Restore button for in-app purchase - is it the same as buying again?

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad, in-app-purchase

I have written some code for a restore button;

```
-(IBAction)restore:(id)sender
{
[[MKStoreManager sharedManager]buyFeature]; 
}

-(void)productPurchased
{

for (UIView *view in self.view.subviews)
{
if (view.tag==2000)
{
[view removeFromSuperview];
}
} 

UIAlertView *alert=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Thank you" message:@"Your restore was successful." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
[alert show];
[alert release];


}

// error restore
- (void)failed
{
for (UIView *view in self.view.subviews)
{
if (view.tag==2000)
{
[view removeFromSuperview];
}
}

UIAlertView *alert=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Your restore has failed." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
[alert show];
[alert release];

}
```

But it prompts the user to 'buy' when they press it? Is this correct? I know essentially the same thing is happening as it is not going to charge them again, but I don't want to submit this code to apple only for them to reject it on the fact it doesn't make it clear enough?

Or have I done the code incorrectly?

Your help would be great appreciated,

Regards,

Agnelli

Answer (score 3):

I think you want to call the method `restorePreviousTransactionsOnComplete:onError:`, not `buyFeature`.

Comment: Hmmmm I still can't get it to work, do you have a code example using the above?

Comment: Nope; I just looked up the docs for your library; what code are you using now? What error are you getting?

Comment: -(IBAction)restore:(id)sender
{
[[MKStoreManager sharedManager] restorePreviousTransactions]; 
}

However, that is warning me that 'MkStoreManager' may not respond to 'restorePreviousTransactions'

The other code (ie changing it to what you said, it didn't like that code, although a variant of it, worked without error for compiling, but however did not actually work :(

Comment: Sorry; without more information about what's not working, there's not much I can suggest. Why don't you try getting the latest version of your library and seeing if you can get that to work? If it doesn't seem to work either, you could post another question with updated code and what behaviour you're seeing.

Comment: Well it puts up the login box asking for iTunes ID etc, but when you put them in, that's it, it doesn't do anything - maybe because I am using it in Sandbox mode? But on the debugger in Xcode it doesn't show anything is being called when I press that restore button?

Comment: That's all it's supposed to do, from the user's perspective. It should be unlocking the already-purchased products, etc. Check to see if the products are unlocked when it completes. (You should be able to get a completion block called if you're using the latest version.)